# jQuery: mouseup and mousedown click handlers

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to replace the text of the lastClick div on the mouseup and mousedown events, but this code is not working. Any suggestions?

```
$('document').on(

{mousedown: function(){ $('#lastClick').html('down');}}, 

{mouseup: function(){$('#lastClick').html('up');}}

);
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div id='lastClick'>not clicked yet!</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$('#lastClick').on('mousedown', function() {
    $(this).html('down');
});
$('#lastClick').on('mouseup', function() {
    $(this).html('up');
});​
```

See this [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/dacCy/)

Comment: You realise you can chain the `on()` methods?

Answer (score 3):

remove your quote

```
$(document).on(

{mousedown: function(){ $('#lastClick').html('down');}}, 

{mouseup: function(){$('#lastClick').html('up');}}

);
```

Comment: that's weird. The page is set up with a quote around document $('document').ready(function()

Answer (score 3):

try this

***HTML***

```
<body>
   <div id='lastClick'>not clicked yet!</div>
</body>
```

***JS CODE***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#lastClick').on(

  {mousedown: function(){ $(this).html('down');}}, 

  {mouseup: function(){$(this).html('up');}}

 ); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

While [Philippe's identified your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12323798/82548) (the unnecessary quotes around `document`) I do think you're vastly over-complicating things, though perhaps only to demonstrate your problem. But, in this case, what you're trying to do in your code could be simply replicated with:

```
$(document).on('mousedown mouseup', function(e){
    $('#lastClick').text(e.type);
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xEwCK/).

And if you do need the string to be `'up'` or `'down'`, then you can amend the above a little with a string manipulation:

```
$(document).on('mousedown mouseup', function(e){
    $('#lastClick').text(e.type.replace('mouse',''));
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xEwCK/1/).

Comment: thank you sir, i admire the elegant simplicity and power of your solution.